# Why restoreState() and saveState() of PagerAdapter won't work?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to save a current state of the `ViewPager` (current position etc.) by implementing two methods in its `PagerAdapter`: `restoreState()` and `saveState()`. However they seem to not work correctly in my case. What I'm doing wrong?

```
@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("instanceState", super.saveState());
bundle.putInt("stateToSave", position);
return bundle;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader c) {
if (state instanceof Bundle) {
  Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
  position = bundle.getInt("stateToSave");
  super.restoreState(bundle.getParcelable("instanceState"), c);
  return;
}
super.restoreState(state, c);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use onSaveInstanceState method from ViewPager? In your Activity/Fragment you can save state of ViewPager by calling this method and pass the result to Bundle.

After rebuilding the Activity/Fragment call onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable p) using

Comment: You should not be calling onSaveInstanceState  and onRestoreInstanceState yourself. Leave it to the Android framework to do so.